# How to find all people's username in company's /home dir

Tags: user-accounts

In my company we all have home directory `/home/user`, I want to test other users' initialization settings, but in `/home` dir, normally I can only see my own user name. However if I know other peoples' user name, sometimes also one or two other person, I can access to their `/home/otheruser`.

So the problem comes down to the point that I have to know their user name first. I want to try to traverse alpabet combinations `[a-z]` with `if [ -d "/home/asuer"]; then testinitializesetting`; fi. But the set is too large and technically impossible. Does anybody know how to list all usernames even if they are accessible but not displayed? Besides, ls -a in `/home` dir also not working.

Comment: What sort of login scheme are you using?  LDAP or NIS or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be able to run `getent passwd` to get a list of every `passwd` entry in the system.  Then you can grab the first field, like

```
getent passwd | cut -f1 -d:
```

but that will also include system accounts so more than just "regular" users